# Use of free() function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I just have a general question about the behaviour of the free() function in C.

Am I right to assume that by calling `free()` it simply frees the memory pointed to by the pointer, but leaves the pointer intact?

In other words, the pointer doesn't need to be reinitialised, just the memory re-allocated, if I want to reuse the pointer?

For example, would this piece of code be legitimate?

#### Original version

```
void foo()
{
    data_t *x;
    int y = 0;

    while(x->data != some_value)
    {
        x = some_function(y);
        y = some_other_function(x);
        free(x);
    }
}
```

#### Amended version

```
void foo()
{
    data_t *x;
    int y = 0;

    x = some_function(y);

    while(x->data != some_value)
    {
        y = some_other_function(x);
        free(x);
        x = some_function(y);
    }
}
```

Ignore the actual code (and the internal structure of `data_t`) and assume that `some_function()` properly `malloc()`s `x`; I just want to know if this is a proper way to manage memory, or do I need to reinitialise `data_t *x` after every free?

*EDIT: I edited the code because I realised it wasn't illustrating my question properly.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Also, note that it is not fair to invalidate someone's answer by changing the question.  I've revised it to show the original code which Mohamed's answer addresses, as well as the revised code.  Assuming that `some_function()` never returns a null pointer, then what you wrote in the amended code is safe and sound — I'm not really sure what you're worrying about, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

freeing `x` and then goto to the next `while` check will cause **undefined behaviour**.

Because in the next `while` check, you make `while(x->data != some_value)` and x is already freed

You have to assign `x` to its next value before make the next `while` check

BTW: even at the beginning of the while (in the first check), you have **undefined behaviour**, because `x` is not initiated to a memory area before the while loop.

---

based on the question **EDIT**

the `free(x)` in the new case has no effect.

when you free `x` the x pointer keep the old memory address that x was pointed on but the memory is not any more allocated it's free.

when you assign new allocated memory to the x after the free the x will be pointed to the new memory area

Comment: sorry, i just got the order wrong in the while loop, my question was more about the behaviour of free and whether i can free something and still use the pointer.. hopefully the edited code will reflect that better..

Comment: NB: the code in the question has been revised and the revision invalidates the comment here — which was accurate when the answer was given.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the amended version of code is the right way to manage memory . There is no need to reinitialise x again. Just you need to make sure that after freeing x , it should never be used. However you can again reallocate some memory to it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

> it simply frees the memory pointed to by the pointer, but leaves the pointer intact?

That is right. if free() is otherwise a normal C function, there is no way it can affect the pointer value you pass in to it. Since C passes arguments by value, free() receives a copy of the pointer you pass to it, and it cannot alter your original x pointer. (It can ofcourse alter what x points *to* )

> In other words, the pointer doesn't need to be reinitialised, just the memory re-allocated, if I want to reuse the pointer?

```
free(x);
x = some_function(y);
```

That's exactly what you do here, you assign x to something else, so this is what one normally would do. 
The pointer contains an address, and you assign it another address.

this is the same concept as:

```
 int x 
 x = function_that_returns_int();
 x = function_that_returns_int();
```

Where you just assign a new value to `i`, there's no need to do anything else to `i` before assigning a new value to it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the abstract language definition in the ISO C standard, after you call `free` on a valid, non-null pointer that came from the allocator, the value of that pointer becomes *indeterminate*. Any use of that value is undefined behavior. An indeterminate value cannot become valid again.

In actual implementations of C, indeterminate pointer values that stick around in your program can be passed around and evaluated without detection, and when the memory is recycled to newly allocated objects, they become indistinguishable from valid pointers, causing various problems.

This doesn't violate the specification, since any behavior whatsoever falls under the umbrella of undefined behavior.

If you write a program which behaves reliably, but depends on such a dangling pointer that is resurrected by a memory allocation, that program isn't well-defined according to ISO C, and it's unlikely to be well defined according to your compiler or operating system documentation, either.

The compiled program could work today, but tomorrow, the malloc code in your `libc.so` is updated so memory is recycled differently, and it breaks.

Testing that a program produces the expected behavior is important, but it's not the complete story.  Behavior also has to depend on some assurances from language specifications, and system and tool documentation, or failing that, some sort of rational inference that lets you take responsibility for the correct functioning of the program.

An example of the latter is that sometimes we can abuse a C compiler at the language level in order to obtain some desired machine code. While this is not defined by ISO C, and maybe not even by your compiler developer, once you have the machine code, then in some sense it doesn't matter how you got it; it can be independently checked to  see that it does what you want. You can take responsibility for it, and put regression safeguards in place which monitor that code for an unwanted change (when the compiler is operated differently, or upgraded or whatever).

You cannot easily take this kind of responsibilty for the behavior of `malloc` and `free`, which are a run-time blackbox whose behavior can change in the field, long after the program is deployed.

Comment: That's quite a complex answer to a fairly simple question.  The key point you are making, I think, is that if you read the pointer after freeing it, you could (in theory) run into problems.  If you dereference the pointer, you are definitely out of order.  But assigning a new value to the pointer variable (`x` in the question) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition check is not valid because x is not pointing to any allocated memory.So it would result in some garbage value.However, if the code goes in the while loop, x is allocated some memory and then it is freed. So x now becomes a dangling pointer. At the next while check also it will contain some garbage value. it caIn some casesn even cause segmentation fault if the pointer tries to access some data which belongs to other process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The best way to deal with the rewritten question would be to edit this answer, not to add a new answer.  You should probably delete this answer.  I trust no-one will down-vote it before you do so; you didn't know the correct protocol, and had obviously not seen the revised question when you wrote this answer.  However, you should now delete it to make sure.